# Python Asyncio producer-consumer workflow congestion / growing queue

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, producer-consumer

I have been writing a Python app, where:

- There is an `async` function `producer` which listens incoming `items` over a websocket, and put these `items` into an `queue = asyncio.Queue()`.
- There is an `async` function `consumer` which does `queue.get()`, and query `item_details` over a different websocket connection.

**The problem:** The average speed that putting incoming `items` into the `queue` is much higher than the speed of the `consumer` to `get` items from the `queue`, and as a result the `queue` is piling up after a while.

**Question:** What is the proper way to scale-up `consumer` *without multi-processing* and *without throttling the incoming connection*? I am not yet very proficient with `asyncio` and `threading`. I thought of running `consumer` in separate workers, but as far as I understand asyncio's `run_in_executor` cannot be used on `async` functions, and there is also this thing that `asyncio.Queue()` not being thread-safe.

Comment: You must use semaphores or async throttlers that could actually limit the number of incoming connections based on your requirement if you are using async.

Comment: @mac_online Sorry for me being unclear on that point. For the incoming items to be processed, the speed really matters for this application, so for me it is not possible to throttle incoming connections. I will add this to the question.

Comment: You could run multiple consumers for the same queue in the same thread

Comment: @NobbyNobbs I'm not very proficient with async stuff, do you mean sth like `asyncio.create_task(consumer())`?

Comment: Yes, something like that. If your task is IO-bound, you could create additional consuming coroutines and it should help. But you'd better put this tasks in some kind of collection - set or list, so you'll be able to implement graceful shutdown or something like that. Don't run tasks to nowhere, it's not manageable.

Comment: Thanks @NobbyNobbs ! I quickly tested it with `create_task` and that actually solves with `n` number of them. I will also checkout graceful shutdown, thanks for the suggestion. If you write an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if the consumer does an IO-bound work, you could just scale its count. And you don't care about multi-threading, because `asyncio` based on idea of non-blocking IO, and designed to work in a single thread. You could or even must use threads to process blocking IO, if there is no native asynchronous alternative e.g. for file-IO, but it's a separate story.

Here is the simple example to illustrate the case when producer creates tasks faster than single consumer could process them. I emulate an IO-workload with `asyncio.sleep`.

```py
import asyncio
import itertools

async def producer(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    """producer emulator, creates ~ 10 tasks per second"""
    sleep_seconds=0.1
    counter = itertools.count(1)
    while True:
        await queue.put(next(counter))
        await asyncio.sleep(sleep_seconds)


async def consumer(queue: asyncio.Queue, index):
    """slow io-bound consumer emulator, process ~ 5 tasks per second"""
    sleep_seconds=0.2
    while True:
        task = await queue.get()
        print(f"consumer={index}, task={task}, queue_size={queue.qsize()}")
        await asyncio.sleep(sleep_seconds)


async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    concurrency = 2  # consumers count
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(consumer(q, i)) for i in range(concurrency)]
    tasks += [asyncio.create_task(producer(q))]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

output for single consumer, queue size constantly grows

```
consumer=0, task=1, queue_size=0
consumer=0, task=2, queue_size=0
consumer=0, task=3, queue_size=1
consumer=0, task=4, queue_size=2
consumer=0, task=5, queue_size=3
consumer=0, task=6, queue_size=4
consumer=0, task=7, queue_size=5
consumer=0, task=8, queue_size=6
consumer=0, task=9, queue_size=7
consumer=0, task=10, queue_size=8
```

output for two consumers, queue is empty

```
consumer=0, task=1, queue_size=0
consumer=1, task=2, queue_size=0
consumer=0, task=3, queue_size=0
consumer=1, task=4, queue_size=0
consumer=0, task=5, queue_size=0
consumer=1, task=6, queue_size=0
consumer=0, task=7, queue_size=0
consumer=1, task=8, queue_size=0
consumer=0, task=9, queue_size=0
consumer=1, task=10, queue_size=0
```